# Boot stuck at dev/sda6 with fsck clean message shown

Tags: 20.04

I dual boot between Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18 and recently after an update I restarted and now Ubuntu won't boot at all.

I don't really know what to do. I'm new at all this Ubuntu stuff, so I need help of any kind.

[image]

Comment: Are you using 18.04 or 20.04? Please click [edit] and advise.